# How to set the opening file as the tags in vim?

Tags: vimrc, load, tags

I have lots of files named by `file.tags, ncl.tags, flod.tags, ...  , fortran.tags`. when  opening `file.tags`, I want to `set tags=file.tags`.And when opening `ncl.tags`, I want to `set tags=ncl.tags`,and so on.

I put the following in my .vimrc, it doesn't work.

```
let g:current_file=expand("%:t")
au Bufread,BufNewfile tags set filetype=tags tags=g:current_file
```

Answer (score 6):

The `g:current_file` is evaluated in your `~/.vimrc` at startup, i.e. *before any file has been loaded*. You need to do the evaluation inside the `:autocmd`; either with `:execute`, but for options, it's more elegant to use `:let &optionname = ...` instead:

```
au Bufread,BufNewfile *tags setlocal filetype=tags | let &tags = expand("%:t")
```